# SQL Server Management Studio Express 2012 - Can't access documents folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to use SQL Server Management Studio to access my Visual Studio database which is saved in my documents folder. When I paste my path into the Attach database dialog, I get this error:

```
    TITLE: Locate Database Files - LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS
------------------------------

C:\Users\Flaxbeard\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Contacts\Contacts
Cannot access the specified path or file on the server. Verify that you have the necessary security privileges and that the path or file exists.  

If you know that the service account can access a specific file, type in the full path for the file in the File Name control in the Locate dialog box.
```

And if I navigate manually to C:\Users\Flaxbeard, nothing shows up on the right. What is my issue?

Comment: Its look like permission error i'm not sure but, have u tried to access from other drives.? Except C: Drive. place your file in other drive try to access it.

Comment: Does this happen if you right-click on SSMS and 'Run as Administrator'?

Comment: RJK, if I put i t in the C: drive, I can select it but the database is shown as read only and in it's original location.

Comment: please check if your user has admin permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the directory in quotation marks